# Objective c pass slider value to another class

Tags: objective-c, slider, uislider

I have a simple question in which i've spent a lot of time trying to resolve.
I have a viewcontroller with slider:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@property (nonatomic) float a;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize slider,a;

- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender
{
    [self setA:self.slider.value];
}
```

And I have another class where I want to get "A" value, which is value of slider

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%f", [vc a]); //return zero
```

What im doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You create a brand new instance of `ViewController` (your `vc` variable). You then try to get the `slider` value from this brand new view controller. You then try to update this new view controller's `a` property with its own slider value. What's the point of that?

Comment: I create vc variable in my SKScene class, slider value i want to using to control ball speed. Sorry im corrected. I dont want to update slider value, just want to properly get it in another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating a new view controller which means it's not linking to the current VC you have running with the slider that has a changing value. You have to get a reference to the VC that has the slider and then you can get the "A" property off of it just by using dot syntax `NSLog(@"%f", activeVC.a);`

Comment: Yes, but i dont know how to do this.

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: Ok you need to give me more details about how this other class relates to your VC.

Comment: Class where i try to get slider value is subclass of SKScene class and no related to ViewController. I want to get slider value to control balls speed in the scene. For example: ball.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(200*sliderValue, 200)

Comment: In that case it sounds like you're trying to save a setting/configuration so maybe you should be using NSUserDefaults to keep track of that.

Comment: Sorry, I want to do this, but i cant i dont have enough reputation for this. Thank you a lot.